How to mock @google-cloud/secret-manager with jest and nodejs
I have spent so much on this but I can't figure out how to mock @google-cloud/secret-manager. I tried the solution in this post but it is not working for me.
I set up a nodejs app to use secret manager. It works as expected. Now I need to write jest tests.
This is the code.
const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require("@google-cloud/secret-manager");
const gcpMetadata = require("gcp-metadata");

const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

module.exports.accessSecret = async (secretName) => {
    try {
      const lastEnabledVersion = await getLastEnabledVersion(secretName);
      if (lastEnabledVersion) {
        const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
          name: lastEnabledVersion,
        });
        return version.payload.data.toString("utf8");
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error occurred with getting secret", err.message);
    }
};

const getLastEnabledVersion = async (secretName) => {
  const projectId = await gcpMetadata.project("project-id");

  const [versions] = await client.listSecretVersions({
    parent: `projects/${projectId}/secrets/${secretName}`,
  });

  // get the last enabled version
  const lastEnabledVersion = versions
    .filter((v) => v.state === "ENABLED")
    .sort((a, b) => b.createTime.nanos - a.createTime.nanos);

  return lastEnabledVersion?.length > 0 ? lastEnabledVersion[0].name : null;
};

I am able to mock gcp-metadata but not @google-cloud/secret-manager
This is my test
const { accessSecret } = require('../../../helpers/secret-manager');
const gcpMetadata = require('gcp-metadata')

const accessResponse = {
  name: 'projects/74390034/secrets/ACCESS_KEY/versions/1',
  payload: { data: Buffer.from('test-secret-value', 'utf-8') },
};
const versions = [
  {
    name: 'projects/74390034/secrets/ACCESS_KEY/versions/2',
    createTime: { seconds: '1725653856', nanos: 943110000 },
    destroyTime: null,
    state: 'DISABLED',
    replicationStatus: { automatic: [Object], replicationStatus: 'automatic' },
    etag: '"1621af4cea5129"',
    clientSpecifiedPayloadChecksum: true,
    scheduledDestroyTime: null,
    customerManagedEncryption: null
  },
  {
    name: 'projects/74390034/secrets/ACCESS_KEY/versions/1',
    createTime: { seconds: '1709052491', nanos: 685270000 },
    destroyTime: null,
    state: 'ENABLED',
    replicationStatus: { automatic: [Object], replicationStatus: 'automatic' },
    etag: '"1621af4bd6dbbb"',
    clientSpecifiedPayloadChecksum: true,
    scheduledDestroyTime: null,
    customerManagedEncryption: null
  }
]

const mClient = {
  accessSecretVersion: jest.fn(),
  listSecretVersions: jest.fn()
};

jest.mock('@google-cloud/secret-manager', () => {
  const mSecretManagerServiceClient = jest.fn(() => mClient);
  return { SecretManagerServiceClient: mSecretManagerServiceClient };
});

jest.mock('gcp-metadata');

describe('Secret Manager', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    gcpMetadata.project = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('74390034');
    mClient.listSecretVersions.mockResolvedValueOnce([versions]);
    mClient.accessSecretVersion.mockResolvedValueOnce([accessResponse]);
  });
  test('should ', async () => {
    const result = await accessSecret('ACCESS_KEY');
    console.log(result)
  }, 7000);
});

When I run this test, this is my output: enter image description here

I was able to solve the issue.
const { accessSecret } = require("../../../helpers/secret-manager");
let gcpMetadata = require("gcp-metadata");

jest.mock("gcp-metadata");

const versions = [
  {
    name: "projects/74390034/secrets/ACCESS_KEY/versions/2",
    createTime: { seconds: "1725653856", nanos: 943110000 },
    state: "DISABLED",
  },
  {
    name: "projects/74390034/secrets/ACCESS_KEY/versions/1",
    createTime: { seconds: "1709052491", nanos: 685270000 },
    state: "ENABLED",
  },
];

jest.mock("@google-cloud/secret-manager", () => {
  return {
    SecretManagerServiceClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        accessSecretVersion: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([
          {
            payload: { data: Buffer.from("mocked-secret") },
          },
        ]),
        listSecretVersions: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([versions]),
      };
    }),
  };
});

describe("Secret Manager", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    gcpMetadata.project = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce("74390034");
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  test("should access secret", async () => {
    const secret = await accessSecret("ACCESS_KEY");
    expect(secret).toEqual("mocked-secret");
  });
});

